# "Team" based graph with connections between groups

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to simulate to teams, so that I can see the grouping of players on one team. Here is what I have in mind:

[image: example]

I have tried making a nearest neighbor graph between all players then deleting the vertices of one team, but the connections pass through red "cells" (eg 16 to 20).

[image: not working]

Also, a nearest neighbor graph of one team does not always connect adjacent cells (eg 19 to 16) and passes through red cells (eg 14 to 18).

[image: not working either]

Here is the full code with everything I have above:

```
ptt = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {22, 2}];
ntt = NearestNeighborGraph[ptt[[11 ;; 22]], 1, 
   VertexLabels -> Table[ptt[[i]] -> i, {i, 11, 22}]];
(* ntt = vertexDeleteKeepEmbedding[ntt,Table[VertexList[ntt][[n]],{n,\
1,11}]] *)
Show[Show[VoronoiMesh[ptt], ntt], 
 Graphics[{PointSize@Medium, Red, Point[ptt[[1 ;; 11]]], Blue, 
   Point[ptt[[12 ;; 22]]]}]]

vertexDeleteKeepEmbedding[graph_, vertex_] := 
  Module[{coords, vertices = VertexList[graph]}, 
   coords = 
    DeleteCases[vertices, vertex] /. 
     Thread[vertices -> GraphEmbedding[graph]];
   Graph[VertexDelete[graph, vertex], VertexCoordinates -> coords]];
```

Any tips?

Comment: Confusing tipic...

Comment: In one sentence I want to find groups of blue/red vertexes that don't intersect cells from the other team

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {22, 2}];
{team1, team2} = {pts[[;; 11]], pts[[12 ;;]]};
```

Is this what you after?

```
teams = GroupBy[Complement[Sort /@ DelaunayMesh[pts]["EdgeCoordinates"], 
    Sort /@ Tuples[{team1, team2}]],MemberQ[team1, First[#]] &];
VoronoiMesh[pts,Epilog -> {PointSize[.02], Red, Point[team1], Line[teams[True]], 
   Blue, Point[team2], Line[teams[False]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

PS:Note the graph of `DelaunayMesh` record the relationship about the vertices of `VoronoiMesh`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!